# How do i add Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Social reference?

Tags: sharepoint-online

How do I add the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Social reference to my project? I can't seem to find it in Visual Studio's Reference Manager.

Comment: I don't know if this is the right answer, but I managed to add Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Social by adding the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles assembly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.UserProfiles.Silverlight dll in your refrence and you should be able to get the namespace.